# Is it possible to link a shared static library built in VS2019 with a VS2010 project?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, shared-libraries

I need a regex library that can return submatches for a project that has to be built on VS 2010. By submatches, I mean for this regex: "(\w+):(\d+)" applied to this input string "deer:1234", the match state is true and I want to retrieve the contents of the two submatches -- "deer" and "1234".  Visual Studio 2010 does not have regex so I tried building Google RE2 in Visual Studio 2019 as a shared static library and then making a simple interface (see below) to provide me with the bare minimum functionality that I needed.  It obviously builds fine in Visual Studio 2019, but when I copy over the re2.lib and the header shown below and try to compile it into my 2010 project, I get this error:

error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1900' doesn't match value '1600'

Note that my interface below does not use any C++ standard library.  It's just a simple class with character array inputs.  I was thinking that if I compile the re2.lib as a shared statically-linked library and then link it with my 2010 project, it should work. But after spending almost 2 days trying to get this to work, I'm open to other solutions.  Will my approach work or if not can anyone recommend a good regex library that compiles in Visual Studio 2010?

```
class RE2;

class __declspec(dllexport) BasicRegex {
public:
    BasicRegex(const char* str);
    ~BasicRegex();

    bool fullMatch(const char* str, char**& submatches, int numsubmatches);
    bool fullMatch(const char* str);
    bool partialMatch(const char* str, char**& submatches, int numsubmatches);
    bool partialMatch(const char* str);

private:
    RE2* gre2;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the short answer is no, at least not with older versions of Visual C++, as documented below:

[C++ Binary Compatibility between Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019)
   [The Great C Runtime (CRT) Refactoring](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-great-c-runtime-crt-refactoring/)

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1):

The message is result of trying to link export  .lib created in  VS2010 with code in VS2019. Since VS2012 it's no longer supported.

Possible solutions to use the .dll are:

1. Recompile .dll or export .lib using new compiler.
2. Load library dynamically.

The former needs source availability and the latter requires that all dependent libraries  were present also may pose problem of finding name for imported functions.

Comment: The reason I thought that statically linked library would work is because I assumed that it would copy in all relevant Windows STL libraries of the VS2019 build that RE2 requires.  If I compile as a DLL, then would that linking not happen and it would try to use the windows STL of whatever the system has installed at runtime (which would be the VS 2010 STL that doesn't have all the features needed by RE2)?